# Instantiating windows.applicationmodel.voicecommands.voicecommanddefinitionmanager from native C++

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-10

I cannot for the life of me find a way to get access to [this class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.voicecommands.voicecommanddefinitionmanager.aspx) from unmanaged ISO C++ in windows 10. I see no headers related to this namespace in the windows SDK. I do see the winmd file, but trying to run midlrt on the idl files output by winmdidl fails consistently, so that route isn't working out for me.

Can someone help me understand how to reference the namespace and class so that I can use WinRT principals to instantiate it from its runtime class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would seem to be to use the [Microsoft Visual C++ Component Extensions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%2B%2B%2FCX) which allows access to the Windows Runtime and CLR like constructs but results in purely native output.  If you wish to link it to something that cannot be compiled this way, it can be place in a separate dll and delay loaded.